# Visual Studio connect to MySql error

Tags: mysql, connection, visual-studio-2015

I successfully established connection from Visual Studio 2015 to  MySQL Server 5.7.

I want to display the Data first (But in the future, the data should not only be retrievable but also allowed to be manipulated.)

But I am already failing in the first step (Which is retrieving).

whenever I try to add a data Set using DataGridView it says that: "You have a usable connection already.".

Reference images here: (From Data Connection to Errors)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SELo.jpg

If someone can please help me resolve the issues.

If the question is not clear enough, feel free to ask more detail.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: @RusArtM workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001594/you-have-a-usable-connection-already-error-in-visual-studio-2015-adding-data-s/39001595#39001595)

Comment: @Nils Guillermin, Thanks. Will try later

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to help you out.  Click on the local host and see if your database tables are listed.

Comment: have the same problem. Tables are listed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not closing and/or disposing the connection object. Either use the same connection object which is still open OR close it open a new connection.