# 'You have a usable connection already' error in Visual Studio 2015 adding Data Source

Tags: mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015; Windows 10;

In the Data Source Configuration Wizard, trying to add a table from a MySQL install on the network. I get up to this step

[image]

When I click 'Finish', I then get this error message:

[image]

Other SO posts refer to this issue, none are resolved. This is a fresh WinForms project, there is no code written.

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround on the MySQL Connector forums (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,648619,649199#msg-649199)

Basically, you want to use Connector 6.9.8, not 6.9.9. So uninstall 6.9.9, install 6.9.8 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

You can keep using MySQL 1.2.6 for Visual Studio. I will add this note:

> Important
>
> Always install MySQL for Visual Studio before installing MySQL Connector/Net.

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html#Requirements in case you are reinstalling everything.

Comment: Nice one, on the mysql website they have 6.9.1 as the default download version (24 Nov 2017) but 6.9.8 is what you need and probably has a bug fix that makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

1. Remove your existing Mysql for visual studio and MySql Connector by going to programs and features in control Panel.
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Download Mysql for visual Studio 1.2.6 [Click here](https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-for-visualstudio/mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.6.msi)
4. Install it before installing mysql connector
5. Download mySql Connector 6.9.8 [Click here](https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-connector-net-6.9/mysql-connector-net-6.9.8.msi)
6. Install MySql connector.
7. Start visual Studio

This should work.