# How to fill a DataGridView in Visual Studio 2017 automatically?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms-designer

### What I have:

- MS VS 2017
- MySql server launched on local host
- Completely installed pack [mysql-installer-community-8.0.15.0.msi](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

### What I need:

- To create a Windows Forms application using an element DataGridView,
  whith bound table columns. I suppose that
  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4yWR.png) radio-button should be active to do it

### The problem I've faced

When I drag an element DataGridView on a form the function of binding table columns is blocked. As far as I understood, I have not connected to my database correctly, however the following code works (that means that connection has been estabilished)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=mydatabase;password=mypassword";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT id, last_name FROM people WHERE id < 300";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

### What I tried

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001594/you-have-a-usable-connection-already-error-in-visual-studio-2015-adding-data-s) solution do not works for me
- created new user account in database
- re-created connection

Comment: Do you have a DataSource defined? You might want to take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bind-wf-controls-with-the-bindingsource

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thank you for so quick response, i have read the article and repeated the actions mentioned there. but when I began to add a new connection i have got an error "You have a usable connection already". Could you give me an advice what I have to do in this situation (if i have to delete the previous one how I am able to do it)?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using code for Consol Application?
If you want to use dataGridView use Load event of your form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=mydatabase;password=mypassword";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string sql =  "SELECT id, last_name FROM people";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add((string)reader["id"], (string)reader["last_name"]);
            i++;
        }
        conn.Close();
     }
```